# keeping an img fixed in place relative to a background point (responsive design)

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I've checked through a few threads here but I haven't found the exact solution that I'm looking for, they are all off slightly.

I want to keep my img fixed in place relative to the background, I'm using a color gradient where I want the centre of an image to be lined up with, however during resizing it moves it off this centre axis and messes up alot of my styling as per the images below:

here is the web page full screen with the black img more or less lining up with the centre
[image: Image before lined up well]
here it is resized to about 50% of the original size and it is completely offset relative to the centre point
[image: Image lined up not so well]

here is my code below:

styles.css

```
:root {
    --background-green: #ccf381;
    --background-purp: #4831d4;
}

html, body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
  }


.main--container {
    height: 800px;
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, var(--background-purp) 67%, var(--background-green) 33%);

}




.headshot {
    position: absolute;
    right: 24.5%;
    top: 15%;
}

img.headshot {
    
    max-width: 20rem;
    width: 50%;
}
```

main.js

```
import React from "react";

export default function Main() {

    return (
        <div className="main--container">
            <div className="sub--main">
                <img src={require("../resources/profile.png")}
                    className="headshot"
                />
            </div>

        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to position the images taking into account the compensation of its size.

```css
:root {
  --background-green: #ccf381;
  --background-purp: #4831d4;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.main--container {
  height: 800px;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, var(--background-purp) 67%, var(--background-green) 33%);
}

.sub--main {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.headshot {
  position: absolute;
  left: 67%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

img.headshot {
  max-width: 20rem;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main--container">
  <div class="sub--main">
    <img class="headshot" src="data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg clip-rule='evenodd' fill-rule='evenodd' viewBox='0 0 24 24' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath d='m21 4c0-.478-.379-1-1-1h-16c-.62 0-1 .519-1 1v16c0 .621.52 1 1 1h16c.478 0 1-.379 1-1z' fill-rule='nonzero'/%3E%3C/svg%3E%0A">
  </div>
</div>
```